# How to derive 3 complementary mutually independent events using the addition rule

Tags: probability

I'm stuck with following derivation of showing the independence of 3 complementary events using the addition rule. My knowledge is a bit rusty.

$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c )= 1 - [P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap C)-P(B \cap C)+ P(A \cap B \cap C)]$

$ = P(A)P(B)P(C)-P(A)P(B)-P(A)P(C)-P(B)P(C)-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)+1 $

= ... (how to further derive?)

$= (1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$

$=P(A^c)P(B^c)P(C^c)$

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your second line

$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c )= 1 - [P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap C)-P(B \cap C)+ P(A \cap B \cap C)]$

$ = \color{red}-P(A)P(B)P(C)\color{red}+P(A)P(B)\color{red}+P(A)P(C)\color{red}+P(B)P(C)-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)+1 $

$= (1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$ [by factorization]

$=P(A^c)P(B^c)P(C^c)$

Comment: Thanks a lot already. 
Can you help me with the factorization. I don't see immediately how to do the factorization. (my knowledge is still a bit rusty)

Comment: Try expanding $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$. Factorization is the reverse of expansion . Familiarity with Vieta's formula helps too.